# GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA and GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore - which one updates Chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I have these 2 tasks in Windows scheduler - GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA and GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore.

I only have Chrome on my machine (which I use sparely).

I am ok with Chrome to be updated automatically.

**I feel that only one job is responsible for updating Chrome.
Is that a correct assumption and which one if yes?**

**And generally speaking - whats the difference between these two jobs (GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA, GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore)?**